# Prestashop 1.7.4.0 cannot load css and js files from hook, in custom module

Tags: module, prestashop, assets, prestashop-1.7

I'm running Prestashop 1.7.4.0 and have built a custom module for posting comments.

I'm trying to load a css file and a javascript file each time the user visits the product page, where the module is being loaded.

```
public function hookDisplayProductComments($params) {
    //...code
    $this->assignProductComments();
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'displayProductTabContent.tpl');
}
```

In the function `assignProductComments()` i have:

```
public function assignProductComments() {
    //...code
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/mymodcomments.css');
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/mymodcomments.js');
    //...code
    }
```

The files are not only not loaded, but there is no trace of them in the page source either.

I mention that:

- both of the files have some content in them
- The directory structure is: `/views/css/mymodcomments.css`, and `/views/js/mymodcomments.js`, in the folder of the module
- Either i leave these assets in the directory, or i delete them, the script still doesn't seem to try to load them

I tried:

- cleaning the cache
- forcing file compilation
- uninstalling and reinstalling the module

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so the answer was that the assets (js and css files) need to be loaded in the `hookDisplayHeader()` function.
So, you have to add a `registerHook('displayHeader')` in the custom module in `install()` function, and then uninstall and reinstall the custom module.

Comment: Works also for prestashop 1.7.3. Incredible that the addJS function doesn't handle this and moreover that is not mentioned in documentation. Thanks for your help!